# Standard SQL; Custom Query Date Parameters Data studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

```
      SELECT 
      event_date,
      user_pseudo_id
      FROM `datasetid.analytics_XXXXXX.events_*`   
      WHERE cast(event_date as date) between cast( @DS_START_DATE as DATE) and cast( @DS_END_DATE as DATE)
 
      GROUP BY 1,2
```

But I keep getting: The query returned an error. Error ID: 52b3aa8e

I have enabled the date parameter option. I tried using the PARSE_DATE as stated here, but I get the same error https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370296#date-params

This table is coming from Firebase, and the event_date is a string, so I cast it to DATE.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved by using

WHERE PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',event_date) BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE) and PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)